# Allow Admin Profile to access Certain Record Types - Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

I would like to create a Validation Rule that allows only System admins to access certain Record types (but still access all available record types). This is a temporary fix until we can update our profiles accordingly.

I am getting

> Error: Syntax error. Missing ')' for the below formula.

What am I missing?

```
IF ( 
$Profile.Id = "000d00000000000", 
AND (
$RecordType.Id = 
"000d00000000000", 
"000d00000000000", 
"000d00000000000",
"000d00000000000", 
"000d00000000000", 
"000d00000000000"
ISNEW() 
))
```

Comment: When you say "access," do you mean view, or edit?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare to a variable every single time. Also, no need for an IF, either.

```
AND (
$Profile.Id = "000d00000000000", 
OR(
$RecordType.Id = "000d00000000000", 
$RecordType.Id = "000d00000000000", 
$RecordType.Id = "000d00000000000",
$RecordType.Id = "000d00000000000", 
$RecordType.Id = "000d00000000000", 
$RecordType.Id = "000d00000000000"),
ISNEW() 
)
```

As an aside, I strongly suggest you avoid using ID values when possible, and stick to names instead. Using ID values are not necessarily portable across orgs.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox. I tested this with a non System admin and I was able to create a record with one of the record types listed in the formula.

Comment: @beauvs01 You might have meant `<>` instead of `=`. The validation rule triggers when the formula evaluates to true.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox. I used <> instead of = and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is configured in the profile settings for the Object

Comment: While this is correct, the question states "This is a temporary fix until we can update our profiles accordingly."

Comment: @DavidReed I'm not sure how Validation Rule could help here